# Log4Net Properties are always false (probably not initialized)

Tags: c#, log4net

I've been using Log4Net to log to a database and it seems simple enough, but when I debug it I'm finding that all of the logging modes are still false.

I've tried to implement the solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658070/why-are-all-my-log4net-levels-false), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133076/log4net-not-logging-probably-not-initialised), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253466/enabling-log-levels-in-log4net) but none of them are working for me.

All of them say basically the same things.. either I need

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "filepath", Watch = true)]
```

in my `AsseblyInfo.cs` or that I could use

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("filepath"));
```

before I call `log4net.LogManager.GetLoggers()`

I've tried both of these, moved them around to various places, put them in the startup project, put them in `Application_Start()` but none of them have had any affect.

**Here's my log4net.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
          name="textWriterTraceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="C:\Projects\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ADOAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <file value="C:\Projects\Log.txt"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level - %message%newline%exception"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data"/>
      <connectionString value="XXXXXXX"/>
      <commandText value="dbo.sp_CreateErrorLog" />
      <commandType value="StoredProcedure" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Date"/>
        <dbType value="DateTime"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Thread"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="255"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Level"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="50"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Logger"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="255"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@User" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Message"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="4000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@Exception"/>
        <dbType value="String"/>
        <size value="2000"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**And my Class code:**

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "../log4net.config", Watch = true)]

namespace ...
{
    public class LogService : ILogService
    {

        private readonly log4net.ILog _log;

        public LogService()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("../log4net.config"));
            _log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger
        (System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }

    //more stuff
    }
}
```

Can anyone see something that I'm missing? I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you include the log that log4net gives you?

Comment: The log simply has all logging properties disabled which makes me think the configuration file isn't getting read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason my particular program was behaving so strangely is because I was using an API to call a Logging Service which used log4net.

I simply had to move the `log4net.config` file to the root of the API and call it by using

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

This is because Log4Net looks in the root directory of the **initial call** which in my case was different than the directory where I was **implementing** Log4Net.